# Python Pandas : joining selective columns from 1 data frame and add to another

Tags: pandas, merge, inner-join

I want to take 1 column from dataframe 'dfGS' and add it to dataframe 'df3'

If I just join the full dfGS to DF3 it works fine, but when I try to specify only 1 column to join I get : KeyError:'Ticker'**

'''df3=pd.merge( df3,dfGS['Shares to Trade'],how="inner",on='Ticker')'''

Ticker is the correct reference column in both df's , so not sure where I am going wrong?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE1sf.png)
[df3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMTKL.png)

[dfGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUhZb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
df3 = df3.merge(dfGS[['Shares to Trade',"Ticker"]], how="inner", left_on="Ticker", right_on="Ticker")
```

OR

```
df3 = df3.merge(dfGS[['Shares to Trade',"Ticker"]], how="inner", on="Ticker")
```